# Replace whole words in a string without replacing replacements

Tags: php, arrays, replace

I need to replace each word only once, and vice versa. To do that, I used a code that does not work, and I can not find an answer to my question.

**Input:**

`hello w1 w2 w12 new1 new12 new2`

**Expected output:**

`hello new1 new2 w12 w1 new12 w2`

I need words / phrases into the text to replace.

**w1** replace with **new1**

**w12** unchanged

**w2** replace with **new2**

**new1** replace with **w1**

**new12** unchanged

**new2** replace with **w2**

***Of course my text in Persian***

My code is:

```
$string="hello w1 w2 w12 new1 new12 new2";

$fword= array("w1","w2");
$lword= array("new1","new2");

$cnt=0;
$string=str_replace($fword,$lword,$string,$cnt);
$string=str_replace($lword,$fword,$string,$cnt);
echo "<h2>Change in string: $cnt <br> New String: $string </h2>";
```

But it is wrong

I also use this code:

```
$string="hello w1 w2 w12 new1 new12 new2";

$fword= array("w1","w2","new1","new2");
$lword= array("new1","new2","w1","w2");

$cnt=0;
$string=str_replace($fword,$lword,$string,$cnt);
echo "<h2>Change in string: $cnt <br> New String: $string </h2>";
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to merge the two arrays but I don't understand the order you're trying to achieve. Could you update the question with clarification?

Comment: Friend, it is really hard to understand what you need but I am sure you need to implement a parser function that breaks your input text and analyses each word to decide what to do. No ready-to-use PHP function will perform your custom action.

Comment: @mkaatman
I have a text that contains some special words. There is some synonyms or equivalents for each word. I want to have new text with synonyms of those words. In other words, I want a program that can recognize some words in the text and then replace them with their synonyms or equivalents.

Comment: This question should be closed as Unclear because your real Persian text is poorly represented by your sample string.

Answer (score 2):

You can tokenize your string with [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php).

Then check the tokens in a reverse loop, and if the truncated token is in the allowed words list, replace it (you can have a mapping array like ["W1" => "E1", ...]). If such a word was already replaced, just go further.

Comment: Please guide in this case more

Comment: Looks, like preg_replace solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/43283826/7832155 is shorter and more optimal.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is lengthy one, but i have tried myself best to get it done.

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/770821)

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

echo $string="hello w1 w2 w12 new1 new12 new2";
$fword= array("w1","w2","new1","new2");
$lword= array("new1","new2","w1","w2");

//---------Working----------->
$replacement=  array_combine($fword, $lword);
$totrimOffsets=array();
$indexes=findIndexes($fword);
$string=preg_replace("/\~\~{1,}/", "~~", $string);
$newString=replace();
//--------------------------->
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $newString;
function findIndexes($array)
{
    global $totrimOffsets,$string,$replacement;
    $indexes=array();
    foreach($array as $element)
    {
        preg_match_all("/\b$element\b/i", $string,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        if(isset($matches[0]) && count($matches[0])>0)
        {
            foreach($matches[0] as $matchData)
            {
                $indexes[$element][]=array("element"=>$element,"offset"=>$matchData[1],"length"=>  strlen($element));
                $totrimOffsets[]=$matchData[1].",".($matchData[1]+strlen($element)-1).",".$element.",".$replacement[$element];
                $string=  substr_replace($string, getSpecialChars(strlen($element)), $matchData[1],strlen($element));
            }
        }
    }
    sort($totrimOffsets,SORT_NUMERIC);
    return $indexes;
}
function replace()
{
    global $string,$totrimOffsets,$indexes;
    $stringArray=explode("~~",$string);
    $newString="";
    foreach($stringArray as $key => $value)
    {
        $newString.=$value;
        if(isset($totrimOffsets[$key]))
        {
            $newString.=explode(",",$totrimOffsets[$key])[3];
        }
    }
    return $newString;
}
function getSpecialChars($length)
{
    $dummyString="";
    for($x=0;$x<$length;$x++)
    {
        $dummyString.="~";
    }
    return $dummyString;
}
```

Comment: @SahilGolati Thank you
I edited my question
I'm sorry that I did not ask my question carefully

Comment: @AdminFile3 Okay let me check for this now

Comment: If the replacement sql commands easier, it set guide
Fword and lword variables are initialized from the database. But text is not in the database.

[link](http://babynames.ir/wp-content/uploads/image-name-girl-boy/meaning_names.png)

Comment: @AdminFile3 I have updated my post for your second question can you please check?

Comment: thanks, But not work

[result] (http://biacafe.ir/wp-content/uploads/tafrihi.png)

Comment: @AdminFile3 I have updated my post can you please check again, I have checked it for various inputs. Now you can check.

Comment: thank you very much,
In English is correct, but in the Persian language is not correct.
Possibly with a small change resolves the issue. please check it

[show details](http://babynames.ir/wp-content/uploads/image-name-girl-boy/inpersian.png) @SahilGulati

Comment: It is nice for English, but it dosn't work for Persian. I want to use that for Persian texts. Would you please correct it? @SahilGulati

Comment: @AdminFile3 I am sorry :( I dont know persian

Comment: Just set the script to utf-8
Exp: strlen function convert to mb_strlen
@Sahil Gulati

Comment: Can you share your persian text so that i can try?

Comment: Yes of course [download php code](http://babynames.ir/wp-content/uploads/image-name-girl-boy/test.zip) @SahilGulati

Comment: @AdminFile3 I share the screen shot. The above was not working just because of the reason there was not match in the string according to `UTF-8`

Comment: This problem will not go away? :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use preg_replace. Tell it to check for space or string beginning or end `(^|.*\s)`and `(\s.*|$)` to avaid replacing partial matches.

```
$string="hello w1 w2 w12 new1 new12 new2";

$replacements = array(
    "w1" => "new1",
    "w2" => "new2",
    "new1" => "w1",
    "new2" => "w2"
);

foreach ($replacements as $from=>$to) {
    $string = preg_replace(
                '/(^|.*\s)'.preg_quote($from).'(\s.*|$)/',
                '\1'.preg_quote($to).'\2', 
                $string);
}

echo $string;
```

if only the first occurrenc should be replaced you can also give this function a limit of 1 as a the 4th parameter.

**Update: Detailed explanation**

`(^|.*\s)`: First match group: String begins, or start of string followed by a space.

`preg_quote($from)`: Your string to replace. It is quoted to support allkind of characters. preg_quote() will escape all characters to not interfere with regular expression control codes. Also takes care of Unicode characters.

`(\s.*|$)`: Second match group: End of string or space followed by rest of the string.

`'\1'.preg_quote($to).'\2'`: The replacement. First group + new string + second group.

**Update 2:**

Got rid of unneccessary group in code and added escaping to be more general applyable for all kinds of inputs.

Comment: thanks But in persian language not work

` $string="کلمه1 کلمه2 کلمه12 کلمه21 جدید1 جدید2 کلمه2";
echo "<h2 style='text-align:right;direction:rtl'>".$string."</h2>";

 $replacements = array(
    "کلمه1" => "جدید1",
    "کلمه2" => "جدید2",
    "جدید1" => "کلمه1",
    "جدید2" => "کلمه2"
);

foreach ($replacements as $from=>$to) {
    $string = preg_replace('/(^|.*\s)('.$from.')(\s.*|$)/', '\1'.$to.'\3', $string);
}

echo "<h2 style='text-align:right;direction:rtl'>".$string."</h2>";
 `

[new image](http://keder.ir/wp-content/uploads/new%20picture.png)

Comment: this input : `w1 w2 w3 w4 w12 w21 w31 n1 n12 n2`

not work and this result:
`w1 n2 w3 w4 w12 w21 w31 n1 n12 w2` @Torge

Comment: Try using preq_quote: `preg_replace('/(^|.*\s)('.preq_quote($from).')(\s.*|$)/', '\1'.preq_quote($to).'\3', $string)`

Comment: undefined function preq_quote() 

@torge

Comment: sorry, `preg_quote`.  See here: Its hard to set up due to the Right to left part. But I managed to do it for one pair at least: http://ideone.com/kSL5cW

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your script is only replacing whole words, use word boundaries around a piped collection of all search strings.  In the callback of `preg_replace_callback()`, search the mapping array for the appropriate replacement value for the matched substring.

This technique will not replace replacements because the input string is only traversed once.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/aoeor))

```
$string = 'hello w1 w2 w12 new1 new12 new2';

$map = [
    'w1' => 'new1',
    'w2' => 'new2',
    'new1' => 'w1',
    'new2' => 'w2',
];

$subpattern = implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', array_keys($map)));

echo preg_replace_callback(
         '#\b(?:' . $subpattern . ')\b#u',
         fn($m) => $map[$m[0]] ?? $m[0],
         $string
     );
// hello new1 new2 w12 w1 new12 w2
```

If word boundaries are not working for your real Persian content, then you'll need to offer better sample data so that a tailored pattern can be crafted.